# How do I test a computed property on a component in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing

I have a component, `foo-table` that I am passing a list of objects, called `myList`.  I'm setting a computed property on the component that sorts the list. See below:

```
// app/components/foo-table.js
export default Component.extend({
  sortedList: computed('myList', function foo() {
    const myList = this.getWithDefault('myList', []);
    return myList.sortBy('bar');
  }),
});
```

How can I write a test to ensure the computed property is sorted? This is what I have so far:

```
// tests/integration/foo-table-test.js
const MY_LIST = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

test('it renders company industry component', function (assert) {
  this.set('myList', MY_LIST);

  this.render(hbs`
    {{foo-table myList=myList}}
  `);

  // TODO
  assert.equal(true, false);
});
```

Comment: what is the current behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The table works as expected, but I want a test to check that the computed property `sortedList` is sorted. The assertion I have at the bottom of the test file is a placeholder for the answer I'm seeking.

Comment: ah, you'll need to test that the render content is in the sorted order

Comment: you can use the find/findAll helpers from https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers

Comment: What are the contents of foo-table, and what have you tried to assert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to test a computed property, you will need to write a **unit** test.

A unit test does not render the DOM, but allows you to directly access the module under test.

```
// tests/unit/components/foo-table-test.js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit';

module('Unit | Component | foo-table', function(hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);

  test('property: #sortedList', function(assert) {
    const component = this.owner.factoryFor('component:foo-table').create();

    const inputs = [
      { bar: 'beta' },
      { bar: 'gamma' },
      { bar: 'alpha' }
    ];

    component.set('myList', inputs);

    const expected = [
      { bar: 'alpha' },
      { bar: 'beta' },
      { bar: 'gamma' }
    ];

    assert.deepEqual(component.get('sortedList'), expected, 'list is sorted by bar');
  });
});
```

You can generate a unit test like this: `ember generate component-test foo-table --unit`

This answer is current for Ember 3.5